# TwinCAT 3 HMI button as a counter

Tags: twincat, twincat-hmi

I want to use a button as a counter in TwinCAT 3 HMI. For example, the work flow is like this way. I have 10 functions and I have to trigger one by one by pressing a single button to trigger the functions in TwinCAT 3.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to link the button to a function (e.g. by linking it to the 'OnMouseClick' event of the button).

The linked function acts as a master function which calls the correct function depending on an internal counter value.
So basically, you design that master function in a way, that it

1. increments a counter every time it is called and
2. calls the correct function depending on the actual counter value.